# Click button not working with javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am calling data with AJAX.
The output of the data comes as JSON.
I am converting this JSON data to HTML code with JS codes.
There is a set-favorite.click event.
It works when .set-favorite is clicked without being called with AJAX.
But it doesn't work when clicking .set-favorite after calling it with AJAX.
How can I fix this?

.set-favorite:

```
$(document).on('click', '.set-favorite', function(e){
    var prd = this.getAttribute("data-prd"), cpage = this.getAttribute("data-cpage");
    e.preventDefault();
    if(prd != null && prd.length >= 1){
        var data        = new FormData(), thisLink = this, fav_result = '';
        data.append('prd', prd);
        this.disabled = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/plugin?plg=load/favorite',
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            complete: function() {
                thisLink.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-heart"></i>';
                thisLink.style.backgroundColor = (fav_result != null && fav_result == 1) ? "#f34f4f" : "#ddd";
            },
            success: function (data) {
                fav_result = (data.result != null && data.result == 1) ? 1 : 0;
                if(data.redirect != null){
                    window.location.href = data.redirect;
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Unknown error!");
                if(cpage == null){
                    thisLink.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-heart"></i>';
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

For example:

Without with AJAX:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-prd="' + value.product.id + '" data-cpage="true" class="btn btn-danger set-favorite">x</a>
```

Clicking the link above works .set-favorite.

But:

```
function loadMyFavorites(){
    var favRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(), fav_table = '';
    favRequest.open('GET', '/plugin?plg=load/list_my_favorites');
    favRequest.onload = function(){
        if (favRequest.status >= 200 && favRequest.status < 400) {
            var favResult = JSON.parse(favRequest.responseText);
            if(favResult != null && typeof favResult == "object"){
                if(favResult.message != null && favResult.message.length >= 1){
                    alert(favRequest.message);
                }
                if(favResult.result != null && typeof favResult.result == "object"){
                    if(favResult.result != null && typeof favResult.result == "object" && Object.keys(favResult.result).length >= 1){
                        for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(favResult.result)){
                            fav_table += '<tr><td class="text-center"><a href="' + value.product.link + '" target="_blank" title="' + value.product.name + '"><img class="img-fluid" src="' + value.product.image + '" alt="' + value.product.name + '" style="width: 5em;height:auto;" /></a></td><td><a href="' + value.product.link + '" class="text-dark" target="_blank" title="' + value.product.name + '">' + value.product.name + '</a></td><td>' + value.time_to.text + ' <br> <span class="text-muted">(' + value.time_to.date + ')</span></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-prd="' + value.product.id + '" data-cpage="true" class="btn btn-danger set-favorite">x</a></td></tr>';
                        }
                        $("#table_my_favorites tbody").html(fav_table);
                        result = null;
                    }else{
                        $("#table_my_favorites tbody").html('<tr> <td colspan="4" class="bg-danger text-center">{$lang->find('nothing_found')|default:null|stripslashes}</td> </tr>');
                    }
                }else{
                    $("#table_my_favorites tbody").html('<tr> <td colspan="4" class="bg-danger text-center">{$lang->find('nothing_found')|default:null|stripslashes}</td> </tr>');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    favRequest.onerror = function(){
        
    }
    favRequest.send();
    return false;
}
```

It doesn't work when clicking the .set-favorite link from here

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your `loadMyComparisons()` call doesn't create any elements with class `set-favorite` (or set-sfavorite), it's `set-compare` in that code block - so there's no "favourite" button to click.

Comment: I am very sorry. I shared the wrong codes. I've just corrected.

Comment: Did you inspect the link and make sure the class is there. Did you add console lines to see if the function is called. Does it find the data attributes?

Comment: Please read [it's not working](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) - not working is far too vague.  Does the event fire?  What's the value of `prd`/`cpage`?  Why are you using `prd.length`?  The ajax doesn't seem to be relevant, can you create a [mcve] that *demonstrates* the issue without an ajax call by cutting down to only the relevant parts?  (ie a working snippet in the question)